# co-ordinate geometry question

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the equation of the lines which passes through the point (3,4) and whose intercept on y-axis is twice that of x-axis ?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the line on a piece of graph paper?

Comment: @Cardinal there is a line that satisfies the conditions (with a negative slope)

Comment: Can you write the equation of a line through a given point?

Answer (score 1):

$y = ax+b$. You have two equations: $4 = 3a +b$, $y_0 = 2x_0$. Can you take it from here.

Comment: @Cardinal Your wrong

Comment: (+1) I was wrong with the English ! you got it

Answer (score 0):

Let our x intercept be (x,0), then let the y intercept be (0, 2x) 
 
Let us then get the slope of the line passing through these two points,
(0-2x)/(x-0) = -2

since the line also passes through (3,4) 
y-4=-2(x-3)
y=-2x +10

which can also be written as 2x +y -10 =0

Answer (score 0):

Let the intercepts of the unknown line be $a$ & $2a$ on x-axis & y-axis respectively then we have the equation of the line: (using intercept form) $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{2a}=1$$ $$2x+y=2a$$ Since the lines passes through the point $(3, 4)$ hence satisfying the equation by the point $(3, 4)$ as follows $$2(3)+4=2a \implies a=\frac{10}{2}=5$$ Hence, substituting the value of $a=5$, the equation of the line: $$\color{blue}{2x+y=10}$$